# sh: ffmpeg: command not found when run command through php

Tags: php, ffmpeg, centos6

I have installed successfully installed FFMpeg on root of my Centos 6 machine (https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos).

My workplace of apache/php is /var/www/html

Now I'm running below command successfully on /var/www/html directory to capture frame from the video file. It's capturing a frame.

```
[root@localhost html]# ffmpeg -i video.mpg -an -ss 30  -t 00:00:01 -r 1 -y -vcodec mjpeg -f mjpeg -s 160x100 frame8  2>&1
```

I want to run this command through php and using shell_exec() or exec() php functions. My php code for running the command is:

```
$cmd = "/root/bin/ffmpeg -i /project/app/webroot/videos/video.mpg -ss 00:00:14.435 -f image2 -vframes 1 /project/app/webroot/videothumbnails/example-thumb.jpg";
$locale = 'en_IN.UTF-8';
setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale);
putenv('LC_ALL='.$locale);
echo shell_exec($cmd);
```

When I'm trying to run command through above php code, I'm getting below error:

```
sh: ffmpeg: command not found
```

Please help me to solve out this problem.

Comment: go to putty and run the command 'whereis ffmpeg'.

Comment: and you know where is exactly your ffmpeg location is there.

Comment: @User I run the command 'whereis ffmpeg' and out put is `ffmpeg: `

Comment: can you run above command in centos command line ans see what is happening? is there any video thumbnail creating are not?

Comment: I faced same problem in long back,i think ffmpeg not installed properly.

Comment: If ffmpeg is installed in centos the path was /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg..if run the command whereis ffmpeg this path( /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg)was shown.

Comment: @User when I run above command fron Centos command line then thumbnail is generating successfully

Comment: @User I'm logged-in as a root on Centos machine.

Comment: ok no problem just give the manual path to above command and run that and check is there any thumbnails are creation through command line or not?

Comment: just follow my link and install once again and check.

Comment: @User Okay, I will try it and will let you know. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

For Video Thumbnail creation we use ffmpeg.

In Linux Systems(centos 6.x) Ffmpeg installation process and Php example:-

This process is done in my centos 6 and created thumbnails using php.

**Step1:-** Please check If any existing ffmpeg available or not in your linux server .If available please remove that files.

**Step2:-** For New ffmpeg installation follow this link
http://root.uabid.com/compile-ffmpeg-on-centos-6-x/ .

**Step3:-** After installation complete check whereis your ffmpeg installed.

> Command:  whereis ffmpeg

type this command in linux command line and check.If for example your ffmpeg path in (/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg).
Use this path in your code.

**Php Example:-**

```
<?php

    if($extension === 'mp4' OR $extension == 'MP4' )
    {
    $video = $timestamp.$imagename;
    $videoname=substr($imagename,0, -4).$timestamp;
    $image = "sites/default/files/content_images/{$videoname}-thumb.jpg";

    var_dump($video);

    $cmd = "/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i    /opt/lampp/htdocs/myproject/sites/default/files/content_videos/".$video." -ss   00:00:01.435 -f image2 -vframes 1       /opt/lampp/htdocs/myproject/sites/default/files/content_images/".$videoname."-  thumb.jpg";

    $cmdstr = $cmd;
    $locale = 'en_IN.UTF-8';
    setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale);
    putenv('LC_ALL='.$locale);
    echo exec($cmd);
?>
```

**Process 2:-**
This is for static file paths:

```
<?php    
    $cmd = "/root/bin/ffmpeg -i /var/www/html/project/app/webroot/videos/example.mp4 -ss   00:00:01.435 -f image2 -vframes 1 /var/www/html/project/app/webroot/videothumbnails/example-thumb.jpg";
    $cmdstr = $cmd;
    $locale = 'en_IN.UTF-8';
    setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale);
    putenv('LC_ALL='.$locale);
    echo exec($cmd);
?>
```

Hope this helps to you & others..

Comment: Try and let me know if any questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot but this code is also not generating thumbnail. There is no error displaying when I run this code. I have checked the whole directory but no thumbnail example-thumb.jpg generated.

Comment: is there any place having ffmpeg...run whereis ffmpeg and see once..if any other palces have ffmpeg path like usr/local/bin/ffmpeg

Comment: `# whereis ffmpeg` command output is `ffmpeg: ` and `# which ffmpeg` command output is `/root/bin/ffmpeg`

Comment: try with reinstall with my link @Ashok...this is a final step...actually default path is /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg.

Comment: I will again try with reinstalling FFMpeg. btw thanks for all your help. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `which` to locate the ffmpeg binary. At least on Ubuntu/Debian based Linuxes the `which` command should be available by default. `which` returns the file path to the preferred executable of any available application. E.g. `which php` should return the PHP installation executable that is used by default for CLI operations. Therefore `which ffmpeg` should return the system default location for the ffmpeg installation.

```
<?php

// shell_exec returns the command output or null on error/empty output.
$ffmpeg_path = shell_exec('which ffmpeg');

if ($ffmpeg_path != null) {
    shell_exec($ffmpeg_path . ' -i file.mpg --snip--');
}
```

Also make sure that the Linux user running the PHP script has access to ffmpeg (e.g. `$ chmod +x ffmpeg`). If `$ sudo which ffmpeg` returns a path but `$ which ffmpeg` doesn't, try reinstalling ffmpeg for the wanted user or play around with the permissions.

EDIT: use care with `which` though, there's no knowing whether a cracker could replace the ffmpeg executable with something malicious (which leads to the above PHP script running the wrong executable).

Comment: when I tried `# which ffmpeg`, I got `/root/bin/ffmpeg`. After it, I made changes in command according to this path and run through php, I got `sh: /root/bin/ffmpeg: Permission denied` error. I also tried to set permission through `# chmod o+x /root/bin/ffmpeg` but no luck

Comment: The PHP user needs access to the ffmpeg executable. Could you try building the ffmpeg application from scratch as non-root and assign executing rights to www-data (or whatever the PHP run process user is)?

Comment: On my MAC shell_exec( 'which ffmpeg' ) also took the carriage return... make sure to filter that out: $ffmpeg_path = str_replace( "\n","", $ffmpeg_path );

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this problem. For me 'command not found' may be the `$PATH` variable problem.

When run this command through php and using `shell_exec()` or `exec()` php functions, you may use different `$PATH` variable compare with running command in linux directory.

For example, the `/usr/local/php/etc/vhostphp-fpm.conf` for my php project is below:

```
env[PATH] = /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
env[TMP] = /tmp
env[TMPDIR] = /tmp
env[TEMP] = /tmp
env[LD_LIBRARY_PATH] = /usr/local/lib
```

but `ffmpeg` command locates in `/data/bin` directory. My Linux's `$PATH` variable contain the `/data/bin`.

So add `/data/bin` to `env[PATH]` variable above can solve the problem.