# FFMpeg working in command line but not in shell_exec

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg

When I convert a video using command line(ffmpeg  -i dust.mp4 -s 320x240 video.flv 2>&1) it does the conversion fine. But when I use the php code it does not. The code is as follows:

```
echo "Starting ffmpeg...\n\n";
$ffmpeg = "~/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg";
echo exec("$ffmpeg  -i dust.mp4 -s 320x240 video.flv 2>&1");
echo "Done.\n";
```

And the output is :

Starting ffmpeg... sh: 1: ~/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg: not foundDone.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Running from command line you didn't use an absolute location of `~/` so it might be finding it on your path elsewhere. In your script you specifically use `~/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg` so if that's not where the executable is located, you would get that error. Try running `which ffmpeg` from the command line to find out the real location. Or just set `$ffmpeg = "ffmpeg"` and let the path find it.

Comment: where is your ffmpeg installed?tell me path

Comment: just type the command (whereis ffmpeg) and click on enter then exact location will be found.just tel me that path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have already answered for this same question just look at that answer,you will know what n=mistake you done.

For Video Thumbnail creation we use ffmpeg.

In Linux Systems(centos 6.x) Ffmpeg installation process and Php example:-

This process is done in my centos 6 and created thumbnails using php.

Just click on this link [Ffmpeg for video thumbnail creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29529577/sh-ffmpeg-command-not-found-when-run-command-through-php/29530203#29530203)

Comment: Thanks...I figured it out

Answer (score 1):

Use the full path:

```
echo exec("/root/example/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg -i /home/site/etc/dust.mp4 -s 320x240 /home/site/etc/video.flv 2>&1");
```

Make sure php has `read/execute` permissions to:

```
/root/example/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg
```

write permissions in:

`/home/site/etc/`

And read permissions to:

```
/home/site/etc/dust.mp4
```