# sh: ffmpeg: command not found using php in online

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg

I have using ffmpeg for generating thumbnail from video.it's working fine in local host.but not generated in online, it just throw "sh: ffmpeg: command not found".

I have check the ffmpeg.exe, and also given video file path, and image destination path..what's wrong with me..

```
 $ffmpeg="ffmpeg.exe";

//time to take screenshot at
    $interval1 = 2;

    //screenshot size
    $size = '320x240';

$cmd1 = "$ffmpeg -i $video -deinterlace -an -ss $interval1 -f mjpeg -t 1 -r 1 -y -s $size $image1 2>&1";
```

Comment: Please post your local and production OS.

Comment: windows 7 in local , in live linux

Comment: And the online environment...is a webhost or something where you have certain control....do you have ssh access...if it is a *nix distro you can run the following command `whereis ffmpeg`....

Comment: now i just check like this,   but it's also throw same error.                                                                                              $cmdstr = $cmd1;
  $locale = 'en_IN.UTF-8';
  setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale);
  putenv('LC_ALL='.$locale);
  echo exec($cmd1);

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me once. I have solved this by specifying the actual path to the ffmpeg executable. Again **ffmpeg.exe** is for windows platform. But your error message seems like you are on linux platform.

If you are on linux platform, simply specifying the path to ffmpeg executable ( Mostly in /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg ) will solve the issue.

If you are using a windows server make sure the path to the ffmpeg.exe is correct. I cant find anything wrong in this code.

If yo uare linux, this answer is worth looking at [sh: ffmpeg: command not found when run command through php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29529577/sh-ffmpeg-command-not-found-when-run-command-through-php)

Comment: how can i identify that /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg?

Comment: Which linux platform are you using ?

Comment: http://oktakes.com/oktakes/admin/ajax/ffmpeg.exe, this is my exe path. how to chenge to  /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg?

Comment: No you cant specify path like that. Can you tell me which LINUX Distro ( like Ubuntu ) you are using. ?

Comment: sorry, i don't know that

Comment: Since you are using Linux run **whereis ffmpeg** from the command line, and it will show you the path.

Comment: You mean how to find which linux distribution you are using ?

Comment: Tell me what do you know about the server that you are using in production and I can pretty much tell. Also, how you are accessing the server ( Not the credentials ) may also help.

Comment: Get root/console access for your server. So that you will be able to install packages inside your server.